# Why is the image through my reversed lens grey and cloudy?

Tags: canon, adapter, reverse-mount

My camera is canon eos 1100d with stardart kit optics 18-55mm IS II.

Yesterday I bought reverse ring KENKO 58mm

[image]

so the result that I do not see anything in viewfinder, only cloud grey image.

Please tell me is it because mms of ring not fit my optics?

How to choose reverse ring for my camera and optics?

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21480/how-to-decide-which-reversing-ring-is-suitable-for-a-lens?rq=1  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10401/how-to-reverse-the-canon-18-55-kit-lens-to-use-it-as-macro?rq=1  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34810/reverse-ring-attachment?rq=1 None of These help?

Comment: Also this blog post might help http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/take-macro-shots-like-this-for-less-than-the-cost-of-a-pizza/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the image in the viewfinder was dark, I would say you are probably not opening the aperture. However, as you mention it is cloudy grey, I think it is more likely that you are simply not getting close enough to your subject. You need to get within a couple of centimetres of your subject to form an image when using a reversed lens.

As Unapiedra said in the comments, there is a guide on using reversing rings in the SE Photo blog, written by a highly talented fellow, that will tell you all you need to know. You can read it [here](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/take-macro-shots-like-this-for-less-than-the-cost-of-a-pizza/).

Comment: Is the highly talented fellow you?...